# Finding a book's subject using Amazon AWS API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm using [PyAWS](http://pyaws.sourceforge.net/) to access Amazon's API. I'm trying to get a book's subject. I know it has something to do with BrowseNode* but not sure how to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know PyAWS but regardless, you probably want to figure out the actual response group and node you need for this.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01/DG/

If by subject, you mean a description of what it's about, the closest I can find to this at a quick glance is the MediumResponseGroup.  The  node seems like a possible fit:

```
   <EditorialReviews>
      <EditorialReview>
        <Source>Book Description</Source>
        <Content>Whether you are a small business or a safety manager trying to decide whether or not awards and incentives are right for your operation, the Safety Incentives Answer Book is must reading.
        </Content>
      </EditorialReview>
    </EditorialReviews>
```

If you mean genre, then that shouldn't be too hard to find either.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, nycdan. I meant genre, as in Biology, etc.